# Не могу связать jQuery c <input type="radio">

Tags: jquery

Доброе время суток, есть вопрос оп jQuery, не как не могу отладить.
Суть вопроса:
Сеть html код и jQuery, не могу сделать так чтобы в каждом шаге при выборе input присваивался класс .active т.е в каждом из шагов можно было выбрать элемент, сейчас выбирается только 1 из всех шагов

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    if ($('input:not(:checked)')) {
      $('div.sweet-block').removeClass('active');
      $('div.music-block').removeClass('active');
      // $('.tab-pane').removeClass('animated bounce');
    }
    if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent('.sweet-block').addClass('active');
      $(this).parent('.music-block').addClass('active');
      // $(this).parent('ul.wiz-cat').addClass('active');
      $('.tab-pane').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.wiz-cat {
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.wiz-cat li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sweet-block:hover,
.sweet-block.active,
.music-block:hover,
.music-block.active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.music-block,
.sweet-block {
  position: relative;
  padding: 35px 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
div.music-block div.wiz-cat-block h3,
div.sweet-block div.wiz-cat-block h3 {
  color: #777;
  margin: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
div.music-block:hover div.wiz-cat-block h3,
div.music-block.active div.wiz-cat-block h3,
div.sweet-block:hover div.wiz-cat-block h3,
div.sweet-block.active div.wiz-cat-block h3 {
  color: #ca2028;
}
div.wizard form div.tab-content.add-share div.tab-pane h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div.wizard form div.tab-content.add-share div.tab-pane h5 {
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.music-block div.wiz-cat-block span.desc,
div.sweet-block div.wiz-cat-block span.desc {
  color: #777;
}
div.music-block:hover div.wiz-cat-block div.img,
div.music-block.active div.wiz-cat-block div.img,
div.sweet-block:hover div.wiz-cat-block div.img,
div.sweet-block.active div.wiz-cat-block div.img {
  border-color: #ca2028;
}
.music-block input,
.sweet-block input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wiz-cat-block {} .wiz-cat-block .img {
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  width: 130px;
}
.wiz-cat-block .img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wizard {
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wizard .nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.wizard > div.wizard-inner {
  position: relative;
}
.connecting-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
span.round-tab {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i {
  color: #555555;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i {
  color: #5bc0de;
}
span.round-tab:hover {
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
  width: 25%;
}
.wizard li:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.wizard li.active:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}
.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
.wizard .tab-pane {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.wizard h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media( max-width:585px) {
  .wizard {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  span.round-tab {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
  }
}
.add-share {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
  <div class="tab-content add-share">
    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
      <h3>Shoose Sweets</h3>
      <h5>Please select the Sweets for the set</h5>
      <ul class="wiz-cat">
        <li class="next-step">
          <div class="sweet-block active">
            <input id="check_sweets1" name="sweets" type="radio">
            <div class="wiz-cat-block">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/sweets/1.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <h3>Sweet 1</h3>
              <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, recusandae tenetur blanditiis.</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="next-step">
          <div class="sweet-block">
            <input id="check_sweets2" name="sweets" type="radio">
            <div class="wiz-cat-block">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/sweets/2.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <h3>Sweet 2</h3>
              <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, recusandae tenetur blanditiis.</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
      <h3>Pleasant Mood with Music</h3>
      <h5>Please select Music for the set</h5>
      <ul class="wiz-cat">
        <li class="next-step">
          <div class="music-block">
            <input id="check_music1" name="music" type="radio">
            <div class="wiz-cat-block">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/music/jazz.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <h3>Jazz</h3>
              <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, recusandae tenetur blanditiis.</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="next-step">
          <div class="music-block">
            <input id="check_music2" name="music" type="radio">
            <div class="wiz-cat-block">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="img/music/blues.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <h3>GARRETT Blues</h3>
              <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, recusandae tenetur blanditiis.</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего есть еще варианты как сделать, но вот мой вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        $('.' + parentClass).removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $('.tab-pane').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
        }
  });
});
```

Суть состоит в том, что у вас уже все определено и каждый `input radio` находится в `div`. Тогда при клике на кнопку, смотрим класс родителя (у вас для определенных групп свой класс) у всех родителей с найденным классом в начале сбрасываем `active`, а потом родителю именно того инпута, на который нажали - даем класс. Остальные же инпуты остаются нетронутыми.

Вместо `parent()`, можно написать и `parent('div')` если угодно. Или что там в дальнейшем будет. Не обязательно писать именно какой-то конкреный класс, чтобы не было привязки

Comment: Благодарю за полный и понятный ответ, это как раз то что нужно, огромное спасибо, я немного не правильно делал, втоптался привязать к input[name='имя'] но в итоге получается очень большой код, Ваш ответ как раз то что нужно, отличное оптимизированное решение.